# kubernetes cluster on CentOS Atomic Hosts

Tags: kubernetes, atomic, centos7, host

The CentOS Atomic Host is shipped without the kubernetes-master package built into the image. Instead, you need to run the master kubernetes components (apiserver, scheduler, and controller-manager) in containers, managed via systemd, using the service files. Do you have any good tutorials on how to form a kubernetes cluster of atomic hosts? the tutorials and the documentations I have seen so far was done on fedora atomic and centOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Kubernetes the Hard Way on Github:

https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a Kubernetes cluster working using the [old contrib/ansible playbooks](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ansible).  While somewhat outdated, they've been tested to work.  At this point the Atomic team is working towards [enabling kubeadm-based installs](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2017/05/testing-system-containerized-kubeadm/).